# Find the first uneven number in random array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

i must create array and fill it with random numbers , between 1-100. From there, i must find the 1st uneven number and print it.
Also have to print 0 if no uneven numbers are in the array.
Heres what i did:

```
int[] tab = new int[10];
int[] uneven = new int[tab.Length];
int i;


           for (i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
               tab[i] = new Random().Next(100) + 1;   


           do
           {
               uneven[i] = tab[i];             



           } while (tab[i] % 2 == 1);   


           Console.WriteLine(uneven[0]);
```

So my reasoning is that i add uneven numbers in uneven[i] as long as tab[i] is uneven,then print the first element of the array.
However, i get "out of bonds exception".

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `tab[i] % 2 == 1` should be `tab[i] % 2 != 0`

Comment: After the for loop, `i` equals to `tab.Length`. Therefore, when you get to `uneven[i]` it is illegal index.
You need to reset i after the for loop, and increment it in the do-while loop to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: You should call `new Random()` only once and then call `Next` on that otherwise your numbers may not be random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop set i to 10 which is outside the bounds of the array. You need to re-set it to 0 before the do loop. Also, you need to increment i.

```
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            uneven[i] = tab[i];
            i++;
        } while (tab[i] % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: Probably provide the corrected code as well

Comment: Lucien, Check out the edits. I added the i++ to keep it out of an infinite loop and also changed == 1 to != 0 like @Rahul said.

Comment: Yes thank you, @TerryTyson.It was exactly the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By the time your do loop starts your "i" variable is stuck on 10. Arrays start at 0 so it only goes up to 9 which is why you're seeing the out of bounds exception.  Here's a small example of what you're trying to achieve:

```
        int[] tab = new int[10];
        var rnd = new Random(); 


        // Create 10 random numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
        {
           tab[i] = rnd.Next(100) + 1;
        }

        // Find the first uneven number
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
        {
           if (tab[i] % 2 != 0)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(tab[i]);       
              found = true;
              break;
           }
        }

        // Didn't generate an uneven number?
        if (!found)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Nothing found");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates an array[] with random numbers assigned to each element.
The second for loop checks if the number is even/odd then breaks the loop if it is odd.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     int[] numList = new int[100];
     var rand = new Random();

     Console.WriteLine(rand.Next(101));

     for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
     {
        numList[i] = rand.Next(101);
        Console.WriteLine($"Element; {i}: {numList[i]}");
     }

     for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
     {
        int num = numList[i];
        if (num / 2 != 0)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"The first uneven number is: {num} in element: {i}");
           break;
        }
        if(i == numList.Count())
        {
           Console.WriteLine("All numbers are even");
           break;
        }
     }
      Console.ReadLine();
  }
```